# Returning value from confirmation dialog using JQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to display a confirmation dialog when a button is clicked. I want to return `true`, when OK is clicked and `false` otherwise.

Associating dialog open call in `onClick` (as given [here](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/), `$dialog.dialog('open');`) event does not serve the purpose. So, as a workaround, I followed an approach, which is similar to this: http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/unobtrusive-custom-confirmation-dialogs-with-jquery. There are two differences between this approach and mine:

1. The example uses anchor tag and,
2. It does not use jQuery UI dialog.

I have modified the code given in the example link, but it does not work. I wonder what I am doing wrong. Is there any cheaper way to do this?

Here is the code, all the CSS/JS are referencing to jQuery CDN, so you should be able to copy the code to see the behavior.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Control Panel</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="http://google.com">
      <button class="es-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" name="changeSem" id="id2">Start Thermonuclear War</span>
      </button>
    </form>
    <div title="Why so serious?" id="id3" style="display:none;">
      <p>You are about to start a war.
        <p>Click OK to confirm. Click Cancel to cancel this action.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id2').click(function (event) {

      if ($(this).data('propagationStopped')) {
        //alert('true');
        $(this).data('propagationStopped', false);
        return true;
      } else {

        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $('#id3').dialog({
          //autoOpen: false,
          width: 600,
          buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              $('#id2').data('propagationStopped', true);
              $('#id2').triggerHandler(event);
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              return false;
            }
          }
        });
        //alert('false');
        return false;
      }
    });
  </script>

</html>
```

---

Clarification: Please note that it's very simple (see the [solution by bryan.taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560872/returning-value-from-confirmation-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog/3561141#3561141)) to do a form submission. What I want to do here is to simulate submission by button click. More like JavaScript's [confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) method.

Comment: Ideally, this example should take you to Google on OK and close and do nothing on Cancel. I would try to avoid explicit $(formName).submit() based solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui dialog box need to return value, when user presses button, but not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous.  The call to

```
$myDialog.dialog('open');
```

will not block, but rather will return immediately.

Instead, one must use event callbacks that you provide in the `buttons` [option of dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons).

This near-duplicate provides a good example:

[jquery ui dialog box need to return value, when user presses button, but not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor)

Answer (score 8):

Your code is a bit convoluted, I think there is a much easier way to do this.  You should instantiate the dialog first, then open it on the click event for your button.  Code would look similar to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('You are about to start a war.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
    .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Why so serious?',
    buttons: {
      "OK": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        window.open('http://google.com/');
        return true;
      },
      "Cancel": function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  $('#myOpener').click(function () {
    return $myDialog.dialog('open'); //replace the div id with the id of the button/form
  });
});
</script>

<div id="myOpener"></div>
```

Here is the jQuery UI Dialog API documentation, so you can see all your options:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: PS I didn't test this code, just pretty much wrote it so you could have an idea of how to approach this issue, so there might be some minor tweaks needed.

Comment: Yeah, this code is alright. The only thing is I want to submit a form.. so what I will do is put $('#formId').submit() inplace of window.open('http://google.com/'); in your answer. But the issue is I want to simulate submission by button click. I realized perhaps the question was not clear, I am adding clarification in the question. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Nishant:  Not really sure what you mean by 'simulate submission by button click'.  Do you mean that you want to stop the submit event from taking place when someone clicks OK?  I guess I'm just asking for you to elaborate on what 'simulate submission' means, can you provide a relevant use case?

Comment: I mean functionality same as <button onclick="return confirm('Please confirm your answer');">Submit</button>. where onClick event gets either true or false based on what user clicked in confirmation dialog.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand, that's very easy.  All you need to do is change the inside two lines of this function:

    $('#myOpener').click(function(){
        $myDialog.dialog('open');
        //prevents default link follow action
        return false
    });

to:

return $myDialog.dialog('open');

and the click event should return the result of the button press.

I'll edit the code above to be correct so you can see.

Comment: No, actually. $myDialog.dialog('open'); just displays the confirmation div and returns true. While JavaScript confirm function waits for user's response and returns boolean based on what user clicked. Your solution would show a dialog box and immediately submit. And that's the reason, I went through the harder route of capturing click event propagation and then restarting the event using triggerHandler.

Comment: Did you get this to work properly? I have validation processes that need to run after a return true -  var where_to_coupon = confirm(pm_info_msg_013);
                                                       if (where_to_coupon== true) {
                                                                    doSubmit=true;
                                                                       return doSubmit;

Comment: This accepted solution is wrong.  See my answer for a correct solution.

Comment: @Nishant: Since this is *your* question, you should not accept an incorrect solution.