# How may I return true or false when I click on confirm dialog button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a snippet of jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.checked').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dirtyvalue = "Test1";
        var textvalue= "Test";

        if (dirtyvalue.toLowerCase() != textvalue.toLowerCase()) {

            {
                var dialog = $('<p>Do you want to save your changes?</p>').dialog({
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {
                            dialog.dialog('close');
                            alert('yes btn called');

                        },
                        "No": function () {
                            dialog.dialog('close');
                            alert('No btn called');

                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            dialog.dialog('close');

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    });
});
```

I want to return true or false on button click; 'Yes' should return true, 'No' should return true, and 'Cancel' should return false.

I already checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor), but this is not solving my problem.
See also my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091001/how-to-show-confirmation-alert-with-three-buttons-yes-no-and-cancel-as-it/9091077#comment11456137_9091077).

My scenario is that I have many ActionLink and TreeView links which navigate to their respective pages. Suppose I am on page 1 where I have this JS, and on that page I have many action links. Clicking on page 2, at that time my confirm should open, and when I click on the button 'No' it should redirect to page 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dialog can't return a value, you must put what you want to do in another function. for example

```
        var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure?</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() 
                       {
                         alert('you chose yes');
                         //call a function that redirects you
                         function_redirect(true);
                       },
                "No":  function() 
                       {
                         alert('you chose no');
                          //call a function that redirects you
                         function_redirect(true);
                       },
                "Cancel":  function() 
                           {
                            alert('you chose cancel');
                         //just close the dialog
                            dialog.dialog('close');
                           }
            }
        });

var function_redirect = function(redirect){
   if(redirect === true){
       //redirect to page2
    }
}
```

you should put the logic you need to implement in "`function_redirect`" (or in whatever function you want) and pass parametrs according to the button pressed

EDIT - if you need to know what button has been clicked, just use the event object that is passed to the function

```
 "Yes": function(e) {
      //e.target is the element of the dom that has been clicked 
      //from e.target you can understand where you are and act accordingly
      //or pass it to function_redirect
      function_redirect(true, e.target);

var function_redirect = function(redirect, target){
   if(redirect === true){
       if($(target).parent().attr('id') === 'page2'){
          //redirect to page2
       }else{
         //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or do the redirect (or whatever) *instead of* the call to 'function_redirect'.

Comment: in the function "function_redirect" how could I know which actionlink is clicked or user click on which btn because every thing is dynamic.

but when i am redirecting page explicitly then its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Dialog works async. So you cant return any value. You should use callback function.

```
$("a").click(dialog.dialog("open"),function(data){
     //do your redirect here
})
```