# Jquery confirmation dialog on asp.net button in repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dialog, repeater, confirmation

I want to do a  jquery confirmation on asp.net button click which is inside repeater but the code below doesnt work.

It doesnt even get in the function Confirmation()

and when the page is loaded confirmDialog div is visible like it's a regular div element not a popup **this is no longer issue but rest remains the same**

what am I missing?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminHead" runat="server">
   <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               buttons: {
                   'Confirm': function () {
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                       return true;
                   },
                   'Cancel': function () {
                       $(this).dialog('close');
                       return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            function Confirmation() { 
            alert("IN");

                $('#confirmDialog')
            .dialog('option', 'onOk', $(this).attr('href'))
            .dialog('open');
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

<div id="confirmDialog">
    <p>ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THIS ACTION?</p>
</div>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="repeaterItem">
            <table id="AdminTable">
              .
              .
              .
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
              .
              .
              .
              <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CssClass="delete" OnClick="ClickDelete" OnClientClick="Confirmation();return false;" runat="server"
                    Text="DELETE" CommandArgument="<%#(Container.DataItem as TagObject).ID %>" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
              .
              .
              .
        </table></div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

-------------------------------------ISSUE-SOLVED------------------------------

My Final Code:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminHead" runat="server">
   <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var deleteButton;
    $(function () {
        $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Confirm': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    __doPostBack($(deleteButton).attr('name'), '');
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function Confirmation() {
        deleteButton = this;
            $('#confirmDialog').dialog('open');
        }
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

<div id="confirmDialog">
    <p>ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THIS ACTION?</p>
</div>
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="repeaterItem">
            <table id="AdminTable">
              .
              .
              .
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
              .
              .
              .
              <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CssClass="delete" OnClick="ClickDelete" OnClientClick="Confirmation();" runat="server"
                    Text="DELETE" CommandArgument="<%#(Container.DataItem as TagObject).ID %>" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
              .
              .
              .
        </table></div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: why have you used **return false** `OnClientClick="Confirmation();return false;"` ?

Comment: Well i have been searching the net for 2 days about this and as i find out return false stops asp.net from doing default action but apparently it doesnt work for me i have tried it without it and it didnt work as well.

Comment: I guess you were suppose to use it like this `OnClientClick=" return Confirmation();" ` , and in the confirmation function return the  true to submit asp page or false to reverse it.

Comment: It still doesnt work and still see the confirmDialog as a regular div at start. Shouldnt it be invisible at start and visible on click?

Comment: ok then , hide the div tag initially by setting the CSS as `display:none`.later when the button is clicked change it back.

Comment: solved the div visible at start issue(it turns out i didnt included IU).But the confirmation still not showing up and the serverside click event still firing

Comment: :Dialog functionality is part of Jquery UI , have u included that library ? u can check this in firebug,by runnuing in firefox browser

Comment: yes i didnt know that it was part of jquery UI but as i said above i included it and the "Div appearing visible at start like a regular div" issue is solved but the rest remains. after including it i tried both my code and your code both still doesnt work

Comment: can u see any error in firebug in firefox or developer tools in chrome ?

Comment: well firebug got frozen on `$('#confirmDialog').dialog('open');`

Comment: I guess it was firebugs problem because it works normal now and issue remains(no errors on firebug)

Comment: oh, i suppose there is something wrong in the way you have implemented the dialog functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking the Confirmation function out of the block. Edited to make it actually work:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Confirm': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return true;
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

    });
    function Confirmation() {
        alert("IN");

        $('#confirmDialog').dialog('open');
    }
</script>


<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" CssClass="delete" OnClick="ClickDelete" OnClientClick="Confirmation();return false;"
    runat="server" Text="DELETE" CommandArgument="asd" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
```

Comment: Confirmation dialog shows up now but when click confirm asp.net serverside click event doesnt fire.

Comment: Maybe you should check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor

Comment: thank you i solved the issue with doPostBack. The post you gave link to, gave me the idea.