# Return value of jquery UI dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

You may find solution over this in many posts([Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor) , [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560872/returning-value-from-confirmation-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog) ), but their solution not working for me.

Here is the normal jquery dialog box written by me.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        buttons:{
            "ok":function(){                                        
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        return true;                                                                    
                    },
            "cancel":function(){                          
                        $(this).dialog("close");     return false;                  
                }
            }   
});
```

I will open the dialogbox with code:

```
var returnVal=$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

I need to return `false`,if user clicks 'cancel' and  return `true` if user clicks 'ok'.

```
var returnVal=$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

I NEED `returnVal` to return `boolean` value(true/false), but it returns javascript `object`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot return something from the OK / cancel functions as they are essentially event handlers that are only processed upon the click of a button.

Use a separate function to process the result :

```
$mydialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "ok": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            processResult(true);
        },
        "cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            processResult(false);
        }
    }
});

$mydialog.dialog("open");


function processResult(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/nz2dH/

Comment: sorry ManseUK (I wanted to accept it with Big Thanks !) but wait wait.. I working over it on my page.. I just provided little code to you here. I am not able to propogate 'result' where form is submitted.

Comment: @Umesh I wanted you to read that page and accept other answers too - not for this question ... can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your problem

Comment: off course ManseUK.. it will take some time. can you please wait for me..?

Answer (score 6):

I have implement Yes/No confirmation dialog with custom message and callback function like this. This is useful, if you like to use the same dialog for various purposes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // prepare dialog
    $(function () {
        $("#confirm-message-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: {
                Yes: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).data("callback")(true);
                },
                No: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).data("callback")(false);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // open dialog with message and callback function
    function confirmMessageDialog (message, callback) {
        $('#confirm-message-dialog-message').text(message);
        $('#confirm-message-dialog').data("callback", callback).dialog("open");
    };
</script>

<!-- The dialog content -->
<div id="confirm-message-dialog" title="Warning"> 
    <p id="confirm-message-dialog-message"></p>
</div>
```

Hope that this helps others as well :)