# Get dialog box value to determine submit the form or not

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-ui, return-value

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="confirm-and-send.php" method="post" onsubmit="return(confirmation());">
    <input a lot of input fields here>
    <button type="submit" name="confirm_and_send" id="submit-button"  class="sent-to-client-bttn" style="margin-left:630px;margin-top: -125px;"></button>
</form>
```

then I have jquery ui function

```
function confirmation(){
   $("#some-div").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        minHeight: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
                'Yes': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(true);
                },
                'No': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
    });
}
function callback(value){
     //do something
}
```

I am following what they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049687/jquery-ui-dialog-box-need-to-return-value-when-user-presses-button-but-not-wor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560872/returning-value-from-confirmation-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog), but it didn't work for me. If I put `event.preventDefault()` the yes button will not submit the for; if I don't put it submits the form before i choose any of the two options. Any can give me a proper example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your button outside of the form.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="my_form" onsubmit="">
        <input type="text" name="x"/>

    </form> 
    <button name="confirm_and_send" id="submit-button" value="Submit" class="sent-to-client-bttn" onclick="confirmation();">Submit</button>
    <div id="some-div" style="display:none">Hi</div>


function confirmation(){


   $("#some-div").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        minHeight: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
                'Yes': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(true);
                },
                'No': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
    });


}
function callback(value){
     alert(value);
}
```

Comment: And remove `autoOpen: false`

Comment: Hey, your idea actually is what I need! to put the button out of the form. The only thing left is configure the callback, I put $('#myform').submit() in the call back and it solve the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry late reply..! Welcome Andrew..!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using JqueryUi dialogue box.. it will not work.. for this purpose you have to use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm)

i explain you what happens when u click ..

it will not stop for ur click .. it will automatically submitted... so u have to try default..browser confirmation

Comment: AmitS's answer have reached the point. The problem of my codes is not the dialog box, instead it is the structure of my form. Thanks anyway