# Show a confirmation dialogue for a specific amount of time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to show a confirmation dialogue for only a specific time, so that it runs out when the user

a) leaves the page

b) doesn't answer in a specific time

```
var acception = confirm("Accept?");

if(acception == true){
    changeStatus("accepted");
}
else{
    changeStatus("denied");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not close the javascript `alert` and `confirm` boxes by the script.You can use jquery [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) boxes instead of confirm box.
Jquery:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    //To close you can use settimeout
    window.setTimeout(
    function() { 
    $('#dialog').dialog('close'); 
    }, 10000);
  });
  </script>
```

If you want confirm message with return true or false means you can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560872/returning-value-from-confirmation-dialog-using-jquery-ui-dialog).